# Not able to access public swift class through framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode7

[image: Project structure]

I created a project and imported it inside this framework. When i load this framework into a demo app, i am able to access the public class `MyTest` inside `MyTest.swift` file but not able to access the public class inside `MessagesViewController.swift`. Am i missing something? Can't we access files inside a project through a framework this way?

Comment: Are you importing `FireChat-Swift` module?

Comment: Can you provide any more information such as any error that you are getting on compiling. Why are you nesting Xcode projects? It looks like your test app is FireChat is your framework? I would say that your project structure is mixed up, but I need more detail to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restructure your project space so that you do not have your application inside your framework, then tackle linking files between the app and the framework.

1. Create a xcworkspace file to contain all of your sub-projects. For more information check out the [Xcode Workspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html) section in the [Xcode Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009328-CH4-SW1) document

[image]

2. Open the workspace file and add your framework and app projects by dragging the xcodeproj files to the "Project Navigation" panel. Be careful when adding the files as Xcode as a tendency to place one project inside another, you don't want this.
   [image]
3. Build your framework and then link it to the the app project. This will also make all you framework files available to your app project as long as they are public(see below for more details). Navigate to the FireChat-Swift app project target in the editor view then from the frameworks project open the product directory and drag the framework file to the Embedded Binaries section of the general tab.

[image]

4. Now your framework is linked with your app project. You will need to import your framework in your app's source code.
   [image]
5. Add new files to your framework and remember they need to be public should you require them to be used outside of the framework - i.e. by your app.

Comment: Superb It Works!!

Answer (score 3):

Did you add `MessagesViewController.swift` to the Target inside the original Project?

To check it just open the original project, select `MessagesViewController.swift` and take a look at the right sidebar (Target Membership section).

Comment: so primitive, but yet so powerful. Just check and uncheck the target membership of a file and it will do the trick :)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, and I fixed mine by going to my framework and adding target membership to `Tests` and `UITests`:

[image]

Strange fix, but I guess it works! ‍♂️

Comment: This is strange but working. Assume, it's relying on project's structure in the sense of targets

Answer (score 0):

This can also occur as part of a bug in Xcode, though I'm not sure what causes it - possibly dragging files from another project into your library. I just fixed this by closing down and restarting Xcode, then cleaning the build folder (hold down `Alt` then select the option from the `Product` menu).