# Unable to access class member inside the pod

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift-class

Im accessing a variable inside a `class` of my `pod`. The members inside the class have `internal` access modifier. But cannot able to access the tenantURL from the networking class. Why this happens?

**SDKCore class**

```
public class SDKCore {

    public static let shared = SDKCore()

    var accessToken: String
    var tenantURL: String
    var clientSecret: String
    var appId: String

    init(accessToken: String, tenantUrl: String, clientSecret: String, appId: String) {
        self.accessToken = accessToken
        self.tenantURL = tenantUrl
        self.clientSecret = clientSecret
        self.appId = appId
    }

    static var getInstance: ApiClient = {
        return ApiClient()
    } ()
}
```

**Networking class**

```
class Networking {

    func performFileDownload(path: String, completionHandler: @escaping (ResultModel<DataResponse<Data>, Error>) -> Void) {
        let fileUrl = SDKCore.tenantURL + path

        alamofire.request(fileUrl)
            .responseData { (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(_):
                    completionHandler(.success(response))
                case .failure(let error):
                    completionHandler(.failed(error))
                }
        }
    }
```

> Use of unresolved identifier 'SDKCore'

[image: Pod Directory structure]

Comment: Did you look at this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37138815/not-able-to-access-public-swift-class-through-framework

Comment: You need to access instance properties through the `shared` instance (for which to be a true singleton, you need to make the initializer of `SDKCore` private) like `SDKCore.shared.tenantURL`. However, the error message should be resolved by the linked Q&A by emrepun.

Comment: I can able to access the pod class members through my project. But not able to access the same inside the pod. That is the different.

Comment: I have checked pod's compile source also. but all these files are listed there? Can anyone help?

Comment: are all files in the correct Target Membership? (right list in Xcode)

Comment: Does the pod file have this target membership option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your code, it clearly visible that tent tenantURL is instance variable not the class one,

```
SDKCore.shared.tenantURL
```

Also Try to clean your project and reinstall the pods

Comment: But Im not getting error on `tenantURL`. The `Networking` Class cannot identify `SDKCore` class, even when im trying to get the instance of that class

Comment: Both class reside in the same group and framework. how can i import that?

Comment: Try to clean your project and reinstall the pods may be this will help

Comment: Thank you so much. this works for me!!!!!!!! You can make your comment as answer. It will help others also